# errors while using two process in one entity vhdl

Tags: process, vhdl

I am trying to write a signal generator with VHDL and state machine approach. it needs to have two processes in an entity and I am doing everything just as same as the course I've passed but I am getting some errors around my process and I think something must be wrong with it. **this is the code**

```
entity pulse_generator is
    port(clk : in std_logic;
        output: out std_logic);
end pulse_generator;

architecture Behavioral of pulse_generator is
type state is (one, two, three, four);
signal nxt, pre: state;
begin
--upper
    p1: process(clk) 
    begin
        if (falling_edge(clk))then
            pre <= nxt;
        end if
    end process p1;
    
    --lower
    p2: process(pre)
    variable count: integer range 0 to 500;
    begin
        case pre is
            when one =>
                output <= '0';
                count := count+1;
                if (count = 300)then
                    nxt <= two;
                    count := 0;
                else nxt <= one;
                end if;
            when two =>
                output <= '1';
                count := count+1;
                if (count = 400)then
                    nxt <= three;
                    count := 0;
                else nxt <= two;
                end if;
            when three =>
                output <= '0';
                count := count+1;
                if (count = 500)then
                    nxt <= four;
                    count := 0;
                else nxt <= three;
                end if;
            when four =>
                output <= '1';
                count := count+1;
                if (count = 200)then
                    nxt <= one;
                    count := 0;
                else nxt <= four;
                end if;
        end case;
    end process p2;

end Behavioral;
```

**and these are the errors**

```
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - Line 19: Syntax error near "end".
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - Line 22: Syntax error near "process".
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - Line 23: Syntax error near "variable".
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - Line 59: Syntax error near "process".
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - Line 61: Syntax error near "Behavioral"
```

**what am I doing wrong?**

Comment: All `end if` lines end with a `;` but one.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I can't believe that was the problem! I fixed it thank you

Comment: When the compiler says "Syntax error", a missing semicolon or another syntax error is in fact usually the problem.

Comment: Note the error(s) can't be duplicated without a [mcve], here missing the context clause (a library clause and at lease one use clause here) also affecting the ability to match error number line numbers. Synthesis tool error messages can be un-enlightening (`ghdl -a pulse_generator.vhdl
pulse_generator.vhdl:19:15:error: missing ";" at end of statement`).